# How to use one dataset's values as another dataset's filter?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three datasets that look like this:

`df_dict1`:

| Code | City | State | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110001 | Los Angeles | CA | 0 |
| 110002 | Houston | TX | 0 |
| 110003 | New York | NY | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | 0 |
| 999999 | Fresno | CA | 0 |

`df_dict2`

| Code | City | State | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 220001 | San Diego | CA | 304 |
| 220002 | Austin | TX | 200 |
| 220003 | Albany | NY | 2004 |
| ... | ... | ... | 3220 |
| 888888 | San Francisco | CA | 320 |

`df`

| Code | Date | City | State | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110001 | 2021-01-01 | Los Angeles | CA | 112 |
| 110001 | 2021-01-02 | Los Angeles | CA | 123 |
| 110002 | 2021-01-01 | Houston | TX | 1112 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 888888 | 2021-01-01 | San Francisco | CA | 1234 |
| 999999 | 2021-01-01 | Fresno | CA | 1113 |

I would like to partition `df` into two new dataframes `df_filtered1` and `df_filtered2`, where `df_filtered1` contains all lines in `df` that share the same cities with `df_dict1` and `df_filtered2` that contains all the cities in `df_dict2`. How can use `df_dict1['Code']` as my filter for `df_filtered 1` and `df_dict2['Code']` as my filter for `df_filtered 2`?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code and it seems to work:

```
df_filtered1 = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(df_dict1['Code'])]
df_filtered2 = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(df_dict2['Code'])]
```